# Determine if difference in class distribution is statistically significant

Tags: r, machine-learning, t-test, data-mining, unbalanced-classes

I have a dataset of some observations with class attribute of values 0 and 1. The dataset is quite unbalanced (class 1 – 15%, class 0 – 85%). Further this dataset consists of 5 years, and the distribution of class values varies between years (let's say class 1: 12%, 13%, 15%, 15%, 14%). I would like to know if this difference in class distribution is statistically significant between years. The results should be a matrix where each year is compared with each other year.

I think I can use a vector of class values for one year and compare it with a vector of class values for another year with a t-test. Is this a correct approach? And is there a way how to get full matrix, so I don't need to run multiple t-tests (if t-test is the correct choice)?

Any comment, help, link, or probably R code snippet would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are the responses independent from year to year, or do you have responses on the same individuals for each of the 5 years?

Comment: Responses are independent from year to year.

Comment: The overall test across multiple years and both classes would be a chi-square test of homogeneity. Across a pair of years, @jsk's suggestion of a two sample proportions test makes sense; it's equivalent to a 2x2 chi-square but is easier to make one tailed.

Comment: @Glen_b Though they are mathematically equivalent, I hate using the chi-square test for a 2x2.  The statistic doesn't give an indication of the direction of the relationship and draws attention away from the fact that what you are really doing is comparing two proportions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the responses are independent from year to year, you could use a two proportion z test for each pair of years you wish to test.  You should be careful though to make sure you account for multiple comparisons in your interpretation of the results.  The following code performs all of the pairwise comparisons and places the p-values from the test into the matrix

```
results <- matrix( NA, nrow=5,ncol=5)
X <- c( 20, 25, 30, 35, 40) #counts for number of class 1 or 0 for each year
n <- c( 50, 50, 50, 50, 50) #sample sizes

for( i in 1:4){
    for( j in (i+1):5){
    results[ i,j] <- prop.test(c( X[i], X[j]), c( n[i], n[j]))$p.value
    }
}
```

If you would like to simultaneously test the null hypotheses that the proportions in every year are the same, you could perform a chi-squared test of homogeneity.

```
prop.test(X,n)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for. I just would like to ask you, if I can use it even when _n_ is the size of whole population, not just sample?

Comment: If you have the proportions for the whole populations then there is no need to use a statistical test which tests whether or not the population proportions are different!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given by @jsk, you could also have a look [here](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/statistics/univariate-inferential-tests/test-for-comparing-two-proportions) for a "written-down" example with the formulas, etc.